# Translating customer prefixes in Magento

Tags: magento, translation

I'm trying to translate the prefix like 'mr.' and 'mrs.' those are set in: *System* >> *Configuration* >> *Customer Configuration* >> *Prefix Dropdown Options*

I need it in English, Dutch and German. Each language is a separate storeview.
I've added the translation to multiple `.csv` files like the themes `translate.csv` and the `Mage_Core.csv`
The default `<?php echo $this->__($prefix) ?>` works on the frontend like the checkout. But in the backend and emails it isn't translated.

Any way to translate those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two ways to fix this.

1. remove the build in prefix and add a new one with custom prefixes.
2. overrule the `Mage_Customer_Helper_Data` class and it's `getNamePrefixOptions` method.

I used Nr2

NR 1: is more work, you will need to update tempaltes. But it is easier to manage for a customer if needs to ad a new translation.

NR2: You can add more prefix values in the config. Then in the class make a switch which to use in which store/language. Adding a new language will probably need to add more code the the class.

What I used to overrule the `getNamePrefixOptions`

```
public function getNamePrefixOptions($store = null)
{
    $pre_val = $this->_prepareNamePrefixSuffixOptions(
      Mage::helper('customer/address')->getConfig('prefix_options', $store)
    );

    // Show all prefixes in the admin
    if (Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
        return $pre_val;
    }

    // Transform array keys to integers
    $pre_val = array_values( $pre_val );

    $lang_code = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDefaultLocale();

    $new_prefixes_values = array();

    // Add language codes here, and add their prefix key's, count starts at 0
    switch ( $lang_code ) {
      case "nl_NL":
        // Set key the same as the value, that's how Magetnto gives it at first
        $new_prefixes_values = array( $pre_val[0] => $pre_val[0], $pre_val[1] => $pre_val[1]);
        break;
      case "de_DE":
        $new_prefixes_values = array( $pre_val[2] => $pre_val[2], $pre_val[3] => $pre_val[3]);
        break;
      default: // other languages
        $new_prefixes_values = array( $pre_val[0] => $pre_val[0], $pre_val[1] => $pre_val[1]);
        break;
    }

    return $new_prefixes_values;
}
```

What I filled in the *Prefix Dropdown Options* setting: `Dhr.;Mevr.;Herr;Frau`
It is a bit hard coded but works and allows you to change the values